# Convert excel/csv file data in string

Tags: java

How to read the excel/csv work book object data in string.

```
String fileData;
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
workbook.write(fileData);
System.out.println(fileData);
```

I dont want to use file serer dependency in my progarm..
So is there any way I can directly write the contents to string variable..

Comment: You need to add more details to your questions so that people can help. You need to add proper tags and avoid grammatical mistakes as well. Perhaps you mean 3rd party lib by saying -"dont want to use file serer dependency"? But here is no in-bulit java API to do that. You can check https://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [org.apache.poi](https://poi.apache.org/) then you can write the `Workbook` into a `String` like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
workbook.write(baos);
workbook.close();
String output = new String(baos.toByteArray(), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

However the string `output` will contain random characters, because the Workbook writes a binary file which is not normal text.

So a better approach is to read the `Workbook` row by row and save the content in a `StringBuilder`, for example:

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(Row r : workbook.getSheet("MySheet")){
    for (Cell c : r) {
        // Assuming the type of the cell is String
        sb.append(c.getStringCellValue()+" ");
    }
    sb.append("\n");
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

The string `result` will contain the content of the `Workbook`.